# How can I count leading and trailing blanks in xml with awk?

Tags: xml, awk, count

what is the best way to count leading and trailing spaces in XML value? In particular, if I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1"> 08 4      </cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">    00 6        </cell>
      <cell id="2">   AL   </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">0 42 </cell>
      <cell id="2">AN  </cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
</dvm>
```

How can I count leading and trailing blanks between ">" and the first occurrence of char/digit and/or between last char/digit and the XML end tag value with awk command? I need to know the sum of leading blanks and sum of trailing blanks and put them in two variables. Thanks in advance.

The output should be:

leading: 8

trailing: 20

Answer (score 1):

Before I begin, let me say that this approach is very brittle; it will fail if your XML is formatted any differently to how you've shown us and even if one of the tags contains certain characters, such as newlines. When working with XML, awk is not the right tool for the job.

That said, you can get the values you want for the input you've shown using something like this:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '$2 ~ /^cell/ { 
  if (match($3, /^ +/)) leading += RLENGTH
  if (match($3, / +$/)) trailing += RLENGTH 
} END { print "leading: " leading+0, "trailing: " trailing+0 }' file
```

Set the field separator to either `<` or `>`, so the contents of the `<cell>` tags is the third field on that line. Use `match` to check for spaces at the start/end of the tag contents. `RLENGTH` is a special variable which is set to the length of the string that matches.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply.
with your code, the output is:
leading:  trailing: 4

Comment: Maybe they're tab characters? It would be simple to treat them as single spaces by using `[[:space:]]` in each of the patterns instead of a space character.

Comment: it's blank spaces, not tabs

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your issue with the data you showed in the question. I would recommend that you try to do some debugging, e.g. `print $3` to ensure that the correct field is being used.

Comment: The script IS correct given the posted sample input.